# how to fix double in flutter even if the last decimal is 0

Tags: dart, double

Hi so i have a double seems like this

d1 = 12.106

and i need to show in to a string  '12.130'

```
 double num1 = double. parse((12.3404). toStringAsFixed(3));
```

well i expected to return "12.130" but it returned "12.13"

the thing i need a string "12.130"  instead "12.13"

```
 double num1 = double. parse((12.3404). toStringAsFixed(4));
```

so tried this one again but also failed

well then number must be shown 3 decimals even if the last is 0

where or what should i have to fix?

Comment: I am little confused about the question, Can you recheck it

Comment: @Juda Where and how do you print the number? It is when you are printing/showing the number you need to use `toStringAsFixed`.

Comment: i need to print this as a text so like this Text('$num'), but the problem is i am using toStringAsFixed(3) already, but it doesn't shows '12.130' it show '12.13'. the answer i need is '12.130'.

Comment: @Juda You should use: `Text('${num.toStringAsFixed(3)}')` . What you are doing now is just parsing the number back into a `double` which does not have a concept of "amount of digits when printed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you have the following variable:
`double d = 12.130;`

and now you want to convert it to a string with the following value: `String s = "12.130"`

This should work:
`String res = d.toStringAsFixed(3) //"12.130"`